# How to setup the angularJs demo project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, angularjs, gwt, maven-plugin

I am very new to angular js and want to learn angular js to apply in our project. Earlier we were working with gwt-rpc and google app engine. Now we want to use angular js instead of gwt. I downloaded gae angularjs guest book project from git hub but i could not be able to set up it in my eclipse because it was showing errors at annotations(@Path, @Get) like below. I have installed maven but still it is showing some errors.

The below link contains guest book project.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-angular-guestbook-java

```
@Path("/guestbook")
public class GuestbookResource {

  private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GuestbookResource.class.getName());

  private List<Greeting> getGreetings(String guestbookName) {
    List<Greeting> greetings = new ArrayList<Greeting>();
    DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key guestbookKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook", guestbookName);
    Query query =
        new Query("Greeting", guestbookKey).addSort("date", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);
    List<Entity> greetingEntities = datastoreService.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder
        .withLimit(10));
    for (Entity greeting : greetingEntities) {
      greetings.add(Greeting.fromEntity(greeting));
    }
    return greetings;
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/{guestbookName}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public GuestbookResponse getGuestbookData(
      @DefaultValue("default") @PathParam("guestbookName") final String guestbookName) throws
      Exception {
    return new GuestbookResponse(guestbookName, getGreetings(guestbookName),
        UserServiceInfo.get("/"));
  }

  @POST
  @Path("/{guestbookName}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public GuestbookResponse signGuestbook(
      @DefaultValue("default") @PathParam("guestbookName") final String guestbookName,
      final Map<String, String> postData) {
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key guestbookKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook", guestbookName);
    // We set the above parent key on each Greeting entity in order to make the queries strong
    // consistent. Please Note that as a trade off, we can not write to a single guestbook at a
    // rate more than 1 write/second.
    String content = postData.get("content");
    if (content != null && content.length() > 0) {
      Date date = new Date();
      Entity greeting = new Entity("Greeting", guestbookKey);
      greeting.setProperty("user", userService.getCurrentUser());
      greeting.setProperty("date", date);
      greeting.setProperty("content", content);
      datastoreService.put(greeting);
    }
    return new GuestbookResponse(guestbookName, getGreetings(guestbookName), null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you use maven for running the devserver? What is the actual error message?

Comment: Yes i ran maven successfully

Answer (score 0):

For AngularJS better use WebStorm with plugins for autocompletion and remote debugging

Comment: can you please share url which is regd to Webstorm plugin for eclipse?

Comment: its integrated just go to plugins in WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using one of the plugins listed at:
http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html

IntelliJ IDEA also has a great support for maven. Using IntelliJ might be another option, although it depends on your taste.